# Vlookup in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

After using Left outer join in query, I want one more new column - if matches data in column "not excluded", if not matches the data in column "excluded"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE`:

```
SELECT tab1.*, tab2.*, 
  CASE WHEN tab1_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Not excluded' ELSE 'excluded' END AS new_col
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2
  ON tab1.id = tab2.tab1_id
```